# Edge detection using pixel brightness transfer function

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, edge-detection

I was reading this research paper, "Edge detection using pixel brightness transfer function" and came across this formula for converting pixels of low luminance, medium luminance, and high luminance to an appropriate size

[image]

where f is the input pixel and a is coefficient.

How should I calculate 'a'?

here is the link for the research paper: [Edge Detection using pixel brightness function](http://koreascience.or.kr/article/JAKO201530848602268.page)

Comment: Sorry can't read the research paper. It seems to be in Korean.

Comment: @Trilarion google translate can help

Comment: Good idea. I don't have time but you could translate it with google. Maybe the translation will tell you how the coefficient is calculated.